# Discord.js v12: filter for awaitMessages() isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't seem to filter the messages out so that the bot will only register a message if the author of the original command before that sent it.

```js
var op = message.author.id;

function first_name() {
  message.channel.send(' — First Name:');
  const verify = (member) => {
    member.id == op
  };
  message.channel.awaitMessages(verify)
    .then(collected => {
      var f_name = collected.first();
      message.channel.send("Please confirm you want your character's name to be " + f_name)
        .then(function (message) {
          message.react('✅');
          message.react('️');
          const confirmation = (reaction, member) => {
            return ['✅', '️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && member.id == message.author.id;
          };
          message.awaitReactions(confirmation, {
            max: 1,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ['time']
          })
            .then(collected => {
              var reaction = collected.first();
              if (reaction.emoji.name == '✅') {
                db.set((message.author).fname, f_name);
                message.channel.send("First name set to: " + f_name)
              } else if (reaction.emoji.name == '️') {
                message.delete();
                first_name();
              }
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Nothing happens when the author of the original message sends the next one.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: That's because you aren't returning anything on your filter function, you should also added a catch statement and the options object incase they don't respond.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing can be simplified by a lot, in multiple different ways.

Firstly, I'd recommend using `async`/`await` for more than one `awaitMessages`, as the code can get very nest-y and hard to look at.

Instead of

```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(verify)
  .then(collected => {
```

Use

```js
var collectedMessages = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {time: /*An amount in ms to wait for messages/*, max: 1 /*Since you're just waiting for one specific message from a user, use this to prevent multiple collected messages./*, errors: ['time']});
//the next part of the code won't execute until a message is collected
var response = collectedMessages.first().content; //collectedMessages is a collection of Messages, so we need to grab the first one out of it (even if there's only one) and then get its content like we do any other Message.
```

As for a good filter, you weren't too specific about what kind of filter you were looking for, but let me attempt to work with what you said.

```js
var filter = m => //filter content;
```

That's a good starting template.

If you're trying to only allow the user who triggered the command to pass the filter, just match IDs like this:

```js
var filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id;
```

`m` is the message being passed through the filter, whereas `message` is the same message that first triggered the bot's command.

And lastly, in case a user fails to reply, simply use a try/catch block, like this

```js
var filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id;
try {
  var collectedMessages = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {time: 100000, max: 1, errors: ['time']});
} catch (e) {return message.reply("Looks like you took too long to reply!");};
var response = collectedMessages.first().content;
```

I hope that helps a little. I'd be able to help you more if you clarified on the problem, and what you need.